# Counting the number of NULLs in a SQL Server Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries like so:

```
SELECT MyId, MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IS NULL;
SELECT count(MyColumn) as MyCount FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IS NULL;
```

The results I get are:

```
MyId    MyColumn
10      NULL
```

Why is the count 0 always in the second query?

Comment: `select count(*) - count(MyColumn) from mytable`

Comment: please show your complete dynamic query. Are you using `sp_executesql` with parameter ?

Comment: Correct - Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. It is in my dynamic SQL somewhere - thanks all

Comment: @Squirrel is correct so deleted the edit and you can see it in the history if you really want to but it's not worth it imo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `COUNT()` function ignores `NULL` values, and so the count in your second query will always be zero.  Either count something else:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn IS NULL;
```

Or else count over the entire table using a `CASE` expression to explicitly count `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN MyColumn IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: What happens when you want to use it as SET @TheCount = (SELECT .... IS NULL)

Comment: In above comment I am using your first answered query but @TheCount is still zero always

Comment: ...are you certain that you have null data for that column?

Answer (score 3):

Count doesn't count null.
You need to do something like this, transform null to 1 then sum them:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MyColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_nulls
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use count(1) rather than column name in the count function as it ignores null value which counting.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, `COUNT(SomeValue)` just counts the number of non-nulls, so you actually needed `COUNT(*)`.

But another way is to subtract the non-nulls from the total

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(MyColumn) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable;
```

A `WHERE` is probably faster though, especially if you have an index on that column.