# What SQL Server dynamic SQL or other operations like cursors remove NULL from a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am trying to do a count(*) on a column name in a dynamic sql cursor but get the following error:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

See previous post for more info: [Previous SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73454289/counting-the-number-of-nulls-in-a-sql-server-column)

dynamic sql is in here:

```
SET @sql = N'
-- Variables
DECLARE @MyTable VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @MyColCount INT = 0

SET @MyTable = ''' + @myTableNameFromDynamicSQL + '''

DECLARE TheCur CURSOR
FOR SELECT name
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@MyTable)
    AND name <> N''MyID'';

OPEN TheCur
FETCH NEXT FROM TheCur INTO @ColName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

IF @ColName <> N''MyID''
BEGIN


    IF @ColName = ''AColumnInQuestion''
    BEGIN
        SET @MyColCount = (SELECT count(*) as MyColCount FROM ' + @myTableNameFromDynamicSQL + ')


        PRINT @MyColCount
        PRINT @ColName
    END

...'
```

Comment: That isn't an error, it is a **warning** (as it states).

Comment: Though there are no aggregate functions in the above, so that warning won't be generated by that code.

Comment: "count(*) on a column name" - so you mean `count(column_name)` then? This is just telling you that some null `column_name` were encountered and ignored

Comment: I want to count the NULLs and I updated the code and the print out is zero even though the column has 1 NULL which I triple checked

Comment: So do you want to `COUNT` the `NULL`s and the non-`NULL` values? Then why not just `COUNT(*)`? If you just want to `COUNT` the `NULL` values, what was wrong with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73454334/2029983) in your prior question?

Comment: @Larnu something isn't right as outside the cursor it works but inside it returns 0 so it's confusing.

Comment: I tested both of the methods both in and out of the cursor but somehow they don't work inside of it but do outside

Comment: I don't think `count(CASE WHEN @ColName IS NULL THEN 1 END)` does what you *think* it does. `@ColName` won't be interpreted as the name of a column, it'll be interpreted as a *variable*. So as that query is within an `IF` where that variable *must* have the value `'AColumnInQuestion'` then of course `count(CASE WHEN @ColName IS NULL THEN 1 END)` is always going to return `0`; `@ColName` isn't `NULL`.

Comment: Ah I see, so if I do the count(*) then how do I get the NULLs as this is wrong somehow 'WHERE @ColName IS NULL)' won't work either

Comment: Honestly, I think you are asking the *wrong* question here. The problem appears to be your misunderstanding of how variables are interpreted within a statement, and think that the values are *injected* into the statement, not evaluated. `DECLARE @Column sysname = N'Name'; SELECT @Column FROM sys.databases;` won't return a dataset with all the names of the databases, it'll return a dataset with every row having the value `N'Name'`. This is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). I would suggest you ask a new question with the *actual* you are trying to solve, and the *full* attempt.

Comment: The question was on point, but the correct way to do it with the constraints of the larger codebase is to use dynamic sql where @ColumnName gets drop in without quotes

Answer (score 0):

The particular error you refer to is not an error. It's a warning, and in most cases can be safely ignored.

Be that as it may, it *seems* (although it's rather unclear) that you are trying to get the number of nulls in each column in the table. If so, you are going the wrong way about it.

You don't need a cursor, and your dynamic SQL is all wrong (most of should have been *outside* the dynamic part), and is also missing escaping/quoting. Instead, the script below will give you the number of nulls in each nullable column. It generates this using `STRING_AGG` over all the columsn at once.

```sql
DECLARE @schema sysname = 'dbo';
DECLARE @table sysname = 'YourTable';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT ' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.name), ','   
    )
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name = @table
      AND s.name = @schema
      AND c.name <> N'MyID'
      AND c.is_nullable = 1
) + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table);

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8351bf46a8aeb0378a18eb001d899c86)